# Prepopulate CCK ImageField with existing images

Tags: 6, entities, media

I have two types of node:

- **Building**, with a CCK imagefield
- **Apartment**, which has a node reference field to a *Building* node, where one building has many apartments

My goal is to to grab the images from the *Building* node being referenced. Is there a way to reuse the images uploaded on the Building node and use that on Apartments node?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

I'm supposing that you **just want to display the images on the node page**, not necessarily filling imagefields on the Apartment node (right ?).

The easiest way is to change the way your reference field is rendered. By default, it should render a title. If you go to *Content Management > Content Types > Apartment > Display Fields*, you can change the display for the node reference field from a "title" to "teaser" or even "full node". That way you can display the images in your apartment node.

Another way, if you really just want the images and not the rest, is to do some coding. For example, in your theme template.php file, you could add the following code (Drupal 6 - because you mention CCK, I guess you're using D6, right ?):

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'apartment') {
    $building_nid = $vars['node']->field_YOUR_REF_FIELD_NAME[0]['nid'];

    $vars['images'] = array();

    // If your imagefield can have multiple values OR only one value BUT the same field is present on
    // another content type
    $result = db_query("SELECT f.* FROM {files}
                          LEFT JOIN {content_field_YOUR_REF_FIELD_NAME} cf ON cf.field_YOUR_REF_FIELD_NAME_fid = f.fid
                            LEFT JOIN {node} n ON n.vid = cf.vid
                        WHERE n.nid = %d", $building_nid);


    // If your imagefield can have only ONE value and is ONLY present on this content type
    $result = db_query("SELECT f.* FROM {files}
                          LEFT JOIN {content_type_building} cb ON cb.field_YOUR_REF_FIELD_NAME_fid = f.fid
                            LEFT JOIN {node} n ON n.vid = cb.vid
                        WHERE n.nid = %d", $building_nid);

    while ($image = db_fetch_array($result)) {
      $vars['images'][] = $image;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank Wouter, Yes I'm still on D6. I would like to show the images on the image upload field of the node forms.

Comment: The "apartment" node form ? That's tricky. It will require some heavy custom code (I've done something similar before...headaches guaranteed). Do the imagefields need to be populated directly, as soon as the user fills in the node reference field ? In that case, you should add a javascript event listener, and fetch a populated imagefield via Drupal's Ajax/HTML system (AHAH) when a node is referenced. That means that you must also create a small module that will receive the AHAH request, fetch the building image, and return the imagefield widget.

Comment: But is it worth it ? I mean, if you change the image in the building node, it won't update the image in the apartment node (because imagefields are all unique, they don't share images). Or, your custom module will have to take that into account as well. Why not just use the node reference field to get the latest and shiny images from the building node ?

Comment: Actually the node reference field is being prepopulated with the nid in the URL (using the prepopulate module)

I was able to load the referenced node with the images but im not quite sure how to show those values in the CCK image fields

Comment: Ok, so the nid is available in the URL (don't know the prepopulate module). In that case, you could write a small module that implements hook_nodeapi() (the 'prepare' operation). Use the building nid from the URL to fetch the images (just as in my example above) and 'prepopulate' the $node object with the images ($node->field_MY_FIELD = array(...)). This is just a theory, but I think it should work.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Im also thinking about what you said earlier that imagefields are all unique.

Comment: Edit: Does it mean that if ever I was able to display the referenced node's images on the imagefield and then the user saves the node form, the images will be reuploaded and not referenced putting the fid in the database table?

Comment: Yes. They won't really be "re-uploaded", but all imagefields are unique. Of course, as long as you don't update any of the nodes (apartment or building), the images will be identical. But as soon as you update one, the change **will not be reflected on the other nodes**. The fields are independent from one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get your hands dirty in code...

Since you have a node reference from *Apartment* to *Building* which Drupal knows about already, another approach is to use Views, [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) to override the rendering of the *Apartment* nodes to pull in the related *Building* node, and thereby allowing you to drop in the image field or a view that contains it.

Also, if you want quick and easy references between Apartments and Buildings to help you when editing nodes or building views, add a Node Reference to the *Building* content type that points at (many) *Apartments*, then use the [Corresponding Node References](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) to automatically keep these reference fields mirroring one another.